React Native Marketing Cloud SDK Kotlin initialization
I'm currently in the process of adding the Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK to our React Native app, following the instructions posted in the README here: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk
Our app is relatively new and the MainApplication is written in Kotlin.
Are there any guides for initializing the SDK in Kotlin vs. Java?  I'm a relatively experienced JavaScript/Java developer but I've never used Kotlin.  I tried pulling the Java code directly into Android Studio and it offered to convert it into Kotlin for me but that's not working.  I'm trying to figure it out manually but would prefer something official so I know I did it right.  Are there any sample projects or a guide I'm missing that would explain how to initialize the SDK in Kotlin?  I did try searching through the StackExchange but didn't see anything so I apologize if this is a duplicate.
Thank you very much
